# System.NullReferenceException in mvc partial view when passing a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add a list in search box in partial view, but I am always getting System.NullReferenceException. A similar option is working when I keep as a separate view. I am not what I am doing wrong when passing List?
Following is the snippet from views and controllers:

1] _layout.cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.Partial("SearchBarPartial2", Model)
</div>
```

2] SearchPartialView2.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchBarPartial2", "Search"))
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyList, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                m => m.CompanyList,
                new SelectList(Model.CompanyList, "fldt", "Value", Model.CompanyList.First().Value),
                new { @class = "form-control" }
            )
        </div>

    }
</div>
```

3] SearchController.cs:

```
public ActionResult SearchBarPartial2(cmpnytable cmpnytable1)
{
    List<Company> objcompany = new List<Company>();
    objcompany = GetCompanyList();
    SelectList objlistofcompanytobind = new SelectList(objcompany, "ID", "Name", 0);
    cmpnytable1.CompanyList = objlistofcompanytobind;
    return View(cmpnytable1);
}
```

Comment: where is the @model on top of view? how are you populating the Model which is passed to the view?

Comment: I am adding following model on the top of _layout.cshtml and SearchPartialView2.cshtml file:  @model myproj.Models.cmpnytable. In fact, I want to provide a dynamic dropdownlist in my search bar.The list is created in the controller.

Comment: either your passing Model is empty or one of the field is

Comment: When I am passing same model in my Home view and adding list in a separate view, it works fine !

Comment: can you post System.NullReferenceException error message to see which line it is causing it?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_searchbarpartial2.cshtml.639c3968.jkgur8db.dll but was not handled in user code. It happens at line:   `               @Html.DropDownListFor(
            m => m.CompanyList,
            new SelectList(Model.CompanyList, "fldt", "Value", Model.CompanyList.First().Value),
            new { @class = "form-control" }
            )
 `

Comment: remove this Model.CompanyList.First().Value , don't select any value by default

Comment: It did not help. The error message also says: "Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: It is definitely caused at @Html.DropDownListFor section in SearchPartialList2.cshtml. However, I also noticed that it did not yet go into SearchController to get the list. Is it getting null when looking for list and I should pass with some value in list (not sure how) ? Same list works when I create a separate view via homepage.

Comment: `CompanyList` is a collection and you cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection. You need to show your model - its needs a property to bind to (say) `int SelectedCompany` and the view will be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCompany, Model.CompanyList)` - and `CompanyList` is already a `SelectList` so creating another identical `SelectList` from it is pointless

Answer (score 0):

Your drop down list declaration already shown evidence of the error:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyList, new SelectList(Model.CompanyList, "fldt", "Value", Model.CompanyList.First().Value), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

As Stephen said, you're assigned the model binding expression pointed to `CompanyList`, which becomes the source of all option tags to be rendered. It has no sense to pass the `SelectList` items as both binding target and source of the option list.

To resolve this issue, place additional model property with integer/string type for holding `DropDownList` selection result as this:

```
// Model
public class cmpnytable
{
    // other properties here
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
}

// View
@model myproj.Models.cmpnytable

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, Model.CompanyList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Since `CompanyList` itself passed to view as `SelectList`, it's no use to create new instance of `SelectList` on the view.